# Conversion between latitude, longitude to UTM notation

Tags: c++, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I have locations coordinates in the form of latitude, longitude such as: `23⁰ 39' 24.8" N` & `58⁰ 11' 36.5" E` , see the pic below. But in my work place I use `ArcGIS` and it seems that doesn't support degree (latitude, longitude) form coordinates. I am planning now to write a C++  code to convert degree form to UTM notation, for example `23⁰ 39' 24.8" N` & `58⁰ 11' 36.5E"`  to `2616726 N` & `621702 E`. I would like to know how can do such conversion?'

[image]

PS:  E = East, N= North.

Comment: http://earth.google.com/outreach/tutorial_importgis.html might help you get started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Conversion_from_DMS_to_Decimal_Degree) explains how to do this. Google earth can use decimal degree notiation.

Edit: looking at your picture i *think* you want to convert to UTM? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) also has this formula.

(note: check Wikipedias formulas with some other source before using)

Comment: You are right, I want to convert from latitude, longitude to UTM, in the second link you put, in `A` formula, what can I put as a value of `λ0`?

Comment: The reference meridian of longitude ;-) But seriously, I did not do much with UTM but I did found this library which can do the conversion you want : http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the lib, but I prefer to code it my self for learning purpose :) Still I am confused with`reference meridian of longitude ` !! Is it constant or what! all what I have are latitude and longitude coordinates!!

Comment: I never did much with UTM but check the link in this answer, http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/13292 I think that site is also better suited to find the answer on what lambda0 actually is...

Comment: BTW. the 40Q in your picture above is part of the coordinate. It is the UTM zone for your coordinates. Without it the coordinates can be in any UTM zone.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to rve's answer, you can implement the lat/long -> UTM conversion by following the equations on Wikipedia.

Alternatively, you could download and install an open-source geodesy package such as [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/) to do the conversion for you.

A third option is to borrow code directly from [GeographicLib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/) or another open-source package, such as this [navsat_conversions](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/kinetic-devel/include/robot_localization/navsat_conversions.h) file. Be sure to give credit to the original author(s) if you do this.